# Can't copy files from remote hard drive

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I'm transferring data file from an old computer to external. Some of the file names appear green on the external hd and I cannot open them. When try, get Word error message: Word canot open the document: user does not have acess privileges. I'm the only user and administrator of old and new computer. Any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

File names and folders that appear green in Windows Explorer are encrypted using Windows built in encryption.

You need to unencrypt them on the original computer, by right clicking on the file/folder and going to properties/advanced/unselect encrypt.